# Database query to select a specific year

Tags: joomla-3.x, php, component

I am trying to convert a small php script to a component for Joomla, So far it is working well. But I would like to make some adjustments.

The view shows data in a table of numbers from specific dates over the last 10 years. 
I have added the column sort to allow sorting of certain columns but wonder if there is a method that allows selection of specific years by default? I would like it to show the current year and then have a drop down list to select prior years as the original script did.

This is the query in my model, any suggestions on how to achieve this would be appreciated
Steve

```
$db    = $this->getDbo();
        $query = $db->getQuery(true);

        // Select the required fields from the table.
        $query
            ->select(
                $this->getState(
                    'list.select', 'DISTINCT a.*'
                )
            );

        $query->from('`#__fts` AS a');

        // Join over the users for the checked out user.
        $query->select('uc.name AS uEditor');
        $query->join('LEFT', '#__users AS uc ON uc.id=a.checked_out');

        // Join over the created by field 'created_by'
        $query->join('LEFT', '#__users AS created_by ON created_by.id = a.created_by');

        if (!JFactory::getUser()->authorise('core.edit', 'com_fts'))
        {
            $query->where('a.state = 1');
        }

        // Filter by search in title
        $search = $this->getState('filter.search');

        if (!empty($search))
        {
            if (stripos($search, 'id:') === 0)
            {
                $query->where('a.id = ' . (int) substr($search, 3));
            }
            else
            {
                $search = $db->Quote('%' . $db->escape($search, true) . '%');
            }
        }


        // Add the list ordering clause.
        $orderCol  = $this->state->get('list.ordering');
        $orderDirn = $this->state->get('list.direction');

        if ($orderCol && $orderDirn)
        {
            $query->order($db->escape($orderCol . ' ' . $orderDirn));
        }

        return $query;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the data directly from the request, setting the current year as the default value:

```
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
$year = (int) $app->input->getInt( 'yearInput' , date('Y') );
$query->where( 'a.yearColumn = ' . $year );
```

Or you can use the `$this->state->getState();` method:

```
$year = $this->state->getState('filter.year');
$query->where( 'a.yearColumn = ' . $year );
```

How do you make sure `filter.year` is populated? If your model class extends `JModelList` then you can override `populateState()` to populate `filter.year`

```
protected function populateState($ordering = 'ordering', $direction = 'ASC')
{
    $app = JFactory::getApplication();

    $value = (int) $app->input->getInt('yearInput', date('Y'));
    $this->setState('filter.year', $value);

    // Set additional state variables or call parent::populateState($ordering, $direction)
}
```

`populateState()` will be called the first time you use `$this->getState()` so there is no need to call it explicitly.

Someone can correct me if I'm wrong but I believe that if you set the field name of your input field to `filter.year` then you wont even need to override `populateState()`, as it'll be populated automatically. In that case you can simply call `$year = (int) $this->getState('filter.year', date('Y'));`. You would need to make sure $this->context is truthy before the first `$this->getState()` is called (else no state will be populated except for `list.start` and `list.limit` and they'll both be set to `0`).

For the internals of `JModelList` (aka `ListModel`) see https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/staging/libraries/src/MVC/Model/ListModel.php

Comment: Drew,  thank you for the link and detailed answer. Steve